# return a json encoded attribute as json decoded in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have a copy of product in order details table saved as json encoded. Now what I want is that when I retrieve it returns a string but I want it to json decoded. I don't want to decode it explicitly I want it implicitly decoded. Some thing in Model like $casts etc.
Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you passing the data; Blade or Vue ??

Comment: You can add a function `getPropertyNameAttribute()` in your model where you return the decoded value.  Side note: next time add your code to your question.

Comment: Why "something in Model like $casts" and not exactly casts as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your column is named `order_details`.

You can add this accessor (full doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `Order` model.

```php
public function getOrderDetailsAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value ?: [], true); //"$value ?: []" ensure a null value will be coverted into an empty array
}
```

Every time you'll call `$order->order_details`, it'll decode the json and return it as an array.